# Why am I getting double reply after submitting in AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to do a comment reply system for my blog.Commenting works good.When I press the reply button for the first time it works normally.If I press it the second time it doubles my reply on the second comment.However, this isn't happening when I refresh the page before submitting the next reply.

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // When user clicks on submit comment to add comment under post
    $(document).on('click', '#submit_comment', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var comment_text = $('#comment_text').val();
        var url = $('#comment_form').attr('action');
        // Stop executing if not value is entered
        if (comment_text === "") return;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                comment_text: comment_text,
                comment_posted: 1
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                if (data === "error") {
                    alert('There was an error adding comment. Please try again');
                } else {
                    $('#comments-wrapper').prepend(response.comment)
                    $('#comments_count').text(response.comments_count);
                    $('#comment_text').val('');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    // When user clicks on submit reply to add reply under comment
    $(document).on('click', '.reply-btn', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get the comment id from the reply button's data-id attribute
        var comment_id = $(this).data('id');
        // show/hide the appropriate reply form (from the reply-btn (this), go to the parent element (comment-details)
        // and then its siblings which is a form element with id comment_reply_form_ + comment_id)
        $(this).parent().siblings('form#comment_reply_form_' + comment_id).toggle(500);
        $(document).on('click', '.submit-reply', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // elements
            var reply_textarea = $(this).siblings('textarea'); // reply textarea element
            var reply_text = $(this).siblings('textarea').val();
            var url = $(this).parent().attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    comment_id: comment_id,
                    reply_text: reply_text,
                    reply_posted: 1
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data === "error") {
                        alert('There was an error adding reply. Please try again');
                    } else {
                        $('.replies_wrapper_' + comment_id).append(data);
                        reply_textarea.val('');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to modify my database in mysql, I was concerned it was something wrong about it at the first time.Everything works fine there.
Here is the code for my reply system:

```
// If the user clicked submit on reply form...
if (isset($_POST['reply_posted'])) {
        global $conn;
        // grab the reply that was submitted through Ajax call
        $reply_text = $_POST['reply_text']; 
        $comment_id = $_POST['comment_id']; 
        // insert reply into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO replies (user_id, comment_id, body, created_at, updated_at) VALUES (" . $user_id . ", $comment_id, '$reply_text', now(), null)";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $inserted_id = $conn->insert_id;
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM replies WHERE id=$inserted_id");
        $inserted_reply = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        // if insert was successful, get that same reply from the database and return it
        if ($result) {
                $reply = "<div class='comment reply clearfix'>
                                        <img src='profile.png' alt='' class='profile_pic'>
                                        <div class='comment-details'>
                                                <span class='comment-name'>" . getUsernameById($inserted_reply['user_id']) . "</span>
                                                <span class='comment-date'>" . date('F j, Y ', strtotime($inserted_reply['created_at'])) . "</span>
                                                <p>" . $inserted_reply['body'] . "</p>
                                                <a class='reply-btn' href='#'>reply</a>
                                        </div>
                                </div>";
                echo $reply;
                exit();
        } else {
                echo "error";
                exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: Because in your click handler for `.reply-btn`, you are adding an _additional_ click handler for `.submit-reply` every time - so each click on the latter, gets then processed _multiple_ times.

Comment: Not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a `'` in their comment (e.g. the word `don't` )  would crash your query because SQL would think the `'` was terminating the input string after the `n`.

Comment: Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See [How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement), [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code, every time a user clicks on an element with the class '.reply-btn', a new click event handler for elements with the class '.submit-reply' is being attached.This is not a good practice because it can lead to unexpected behavior.
like if you click on reply button more than one then when you click on submit it will submit how many time you click on '.reply-btn'.(After Page Refresh).
As see below in Example

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.reply').click(function(){
    $('.submit').click(function(){
        alert('hi');
        })
        
  
  } 
  )
  
 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" class="reply">Reply</button>
<button type="button" class="submit">Submit</button>
</body>
```